# 503 Service Unavailable ,error 503 when using sudo apt-get update , on wsl ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on wsl on my pc and I get this error 503 when I use the command sudo apt-get update, I need help, I have been getting this error for many days. I have used other DNS, user agent, used some ubuntu mirrors and the error continues.

```
 Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
      503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
    Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
      503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
    Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
      503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
    Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
      503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
    Reading package lists... Done
    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
    W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
    W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://askubuntu.com/a/1348410

It's possibly an issue with the architecture
"i386 and amd64 are for the x86 and x86_64 architectures respectively. Unfortunately, ARM processors do not have the capacity to speak x86 in any way."